# Clojure: apply println to multiple strings scrambles output

Tags: clojure, apply, println

In Clojure 1.11, I'm evaluating this term:

```clj
(apply println "foo\n" "bar\n" "baz\n")
```

I expect the following output:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

However, I'm getting *this*:

```
foo
 bar
 b a z
```

The first line is as I need it. The second line contains a leading space. The third line has a superfluous space before each letter.

Why is behaving `apply`/`println` like that, and how can I get the desired output?

Comment: you could also use common lisp style formatting: `(clojure.pprint/cl-format true "~@{~a~%~}" "some" "multiline" "string")` or `(clojure.pprint/cl-format true "~{~a~%~}" ["some" "multiline" "string"])` depending on whether you need varargs or not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leading spaces come from the fact that `println` adds spaces when printing its arguments. E.g. try `(println 1 2 3)` - you'll get `1 2 3` in the output.

The last line comes out as it does because you're using `apply`. `apply` treats the last argument as a collection as passes its items as separate arguments to the target function. So in this case you most likely don't need `apply` at all.

To achieve what you want, you should use something like `(run! print ["foo\n" "bar\n" "baz\n"])`. Or use `println` and don't add `\n` yourself since `println` does that for you.

Comment: Thanks, `run!` is exactly what I needed, since `apply` deals with varargs, and not with a collection.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are adding your own linefeeds,

```
(print (str "foo\n" "bar\n" "baz\n"))
```

with result

```
foo
bar
baz
```

is by far the simplest & clearest option.  The purpose of `apply` is if you have several items contained in a sequence:

```
(apply print [ "foo\n" "bar\n" "baz\n" ] )
```

however, `print` till adds in a `\space` in between each token!  Doh!

```
foo
 bar
 baz
```

So if you do have the 3 args in a vector, you need one of these:

```
  (print (apply str            ["foo\n" "bar\n" "baz\n"]))
  (print (clojure.string/join  ["foo\n" "bar\n" "baz\n"]))
```

both of which produce the desired result.

Comment: And if the line breaks are not already there, also `(println (clojure.string/join "\n" ["foo" "bar" "baz"]))`

Answer (score 2):

Another thought:

```clj
user> (apply println "foo\n" "bar\n" "baz\n")
foo
 bar
 b a z 

nil
user> (print (str "foo\n" "bar\n" "baz\n"))
foo
bar
baz
nil
```